# Trying to identify a specific element for a website extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip

**Edit**: This is very dumb of me but I just realized that this whole problem is stemming from qtip. It seems that it is only generating the necessary code once the user hovers over the necessary area. No idea why I didn't even think to look over that. If anyone is familiar with qtip and knows a good way to identify the element the moment it's actually generated I would appreciate the help. Sorry for those who have already given good advice

**Edit 2**: I figured it out, thank's for the help those that did. This is the code I used to look for the event that triggered qtip to create the element I needed to identify and then have it search for it.

```
document.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  if (target.classList.contains('pre-qtip-content')) {
    var elements = target.querySelectorAll("a.wl-item.dropdown-item.added");
    var result = false;
    elements.forEach(function(element) {
      if (element.innerText.search("Completed") >= 0) {
        console.log("Successfully Identified");
        result = true;
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
});
```

Not sure if this is entirely correct but it currently functions so I'm gonna run with it

---

I'm currently trying to write an extension for chrome for a website to have some QoL upgrades, however I'm basically brand new when it comes to coding and having a lot of trouble trying to identify a specific element on the site. There's more that needs to be done after that but at this point I'm just trying to make sure I can actually grab it and print something to console to verify it's been pulled.

So this is my current code:

```
function replaceCheck() {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".wl-item.dropdown-item.added > a");
  
    elements.forEach((element) => {
      if (element.textContent.includes("Completed")) {
        console.log("Successfully Identified");
      }
    });
  }
```

With this I'm trying to grab the following element from a site:
[Image of website element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obOC3.png)

The problem is is that nothing is printing to console when I run it, I need the code to include the "Completed" string as there are other possible strings depending on the option a user selects from a drop down.

Now for some additional clarification, I learned javascript self taught like 6 years ago now and never actually used it for anything really, so I basically have no idea what I'm doing at this point. This code was originally written up with the help of AI to get a starting point and tweaked it from there so this code could be completely incorrect in every way just trying to get an idea at this point.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: You may also not be aware, but `.includes()` is usually for an Array, not Strings, yet it can work like that. Consider using `.search()` or `.substring()` as an alternative.

Comment: gotcha, i just tried search and substring with no luck but i appreciate the advice there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```
function replaceCheck() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll("a.wl-item.dropdown-item.added");
  var result = false;
  elements.forEach((element) => {
    if (element.innerText.search("Completed") >= 0) {
      console.log("Successfully Identified");
      result = true;
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Using `textContent` might be more aggressive then you need. I used `innerText` property.

> The `textContent` property sets or returns the text content of the specified node, and **all its descendants**.

Versus:

> The `innerText` property sets or returns the text content of an element.

It's not clear, as you didn't provide a complete example, how you are using or calling the function, so I am assuming it may be used in a logical statement.

Search will returns the index (position) of the first match or `-1` if not found. This example is case sensitive, so it must match "Completed" exacly.

Comment: sorry i forgot to provide the full information, I currently just have it as `window.addEventListener("load", replaceCheck);` at the end as thats the only way I know of at this time to get it to run after the page has fully loaded

i tried the code you gave me and nothing came up on log, im not sure what more information you may need but it looks like as far as I can tell the site uses qtip for this which is one more thing I did not add

Comment: @Ori this suggests that the elements do not have the Classes you suggested. Please edit your post and include a [mcve].

Comment: Okay so this worked perfectly when I realized the problem was me being blind and not knowing how qtip worked. The element is not generated until the user hovers their mouse over the area that generates it. Now with that being said would you happen to know of any ways to print it in console the moment the element is generated or would this just need to be a timeout or API solution do you think

Comment: @Ori the only way to do that would be to add code to whatever is hooked on to the mouse over event.

Comment: Ah yea I ended up figuring it out, I put it on the second edit. I appreciate all your help though.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to find the  tag inside the a tag, try removing the "> a" because the ".wl-item.dropdown-item.added" is already it

Comment: It would be nice if you can add a working example as part of your answer.

Comment: in the image you provided this should be the correct path to the element:
`const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".wl-item.dropdown-item.added");`

or if you need it independent of its state, i would recommend to search only by:

`const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".wl-item.dropdown-item");`

Comment: yes sorry i forgot to update that on here, I did remove it and it did not help, I just added it incase it would help in some way as part of the troubleshooting

Comment: where are you calling the replaceCheck function?

Comment: currently i have it being called at the end with `window.addEventListener("load", replaceCheck);` right now

Comment: is tihs script imported on the html?

Comment: I will be completely honest here, not entirely sure what you mean by this question if you could maybe be more specific or describe what that entails. As far the codes ability to run I do have another section in the code for a different function and that one works fine so I would assume theres no problem if I'm understanding your question correctly